# optimization statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

**This query displays the 6 rows.
It is necessary to output 2 rows, and that would be all the columns**

```
SELECT 
    D.RIND_S,
    D.RIND_D,
    D.CUIIO,
    D.CAPITOL,
    D.CUATM,
    D.ID_MD_S,
    D.ID_MD_D,
    SUM(COL1_S) COL1_S,
    SUM(COL1_D) COL1_D 
    FROM (

    SELECT

          CASE WHEN D.RIND IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6') THEN D.RIND  END   RIND_S,
          CASE WHEN D.RIND   NOT IN ('00','--','1','2','3','4','5','6') THEN D.RIND  END   RIND_D,
          D.CUIIO    AS CUIIO,
          D.CAPITOL  AS CAPITOL,
          D.CUATM    AS CUATM  ,
          CASE WHEN D.ID_MD IN (11788,11789,11790,11791,11792,11793)      THEN    ID_MD END  AS ID_MD_S,
          CASE WHEN D.ID_MD IN (11795,11796,11797,11798,11799,11800,11801,11802,11803,11804,11805,12521,12238,12240,12241,12524,12242)    THEN    ID_MD END  AS  ID_MD_D,
          CASE WHEN D.RIND IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')     THEN    CIS2.NVAL(D.COL1) END   AS COL1_S,
          CASE WHEN D.RIND   NOT IN ('00','--','1','2','3','4','5','6')      THEN    CIS2.NVAL(D.COL1) END AS  COL1_D



        FROM
          CIS2.VW_DATA_ALL D



        WHERE
         (D.PERIOADA =:pPERIOADA) AND   
          D.FORM IN (20) AND
          D.CAPITOL IN (1010) 
          AND D.CUIIO IN (5698200,38985903)

        ) D


        GROUP BY 
        D.RIND_S,
        D.RIND_D,
        D.ID_MD_S,
        D.ID_MD_D,
        D.CUIIO,
        D.CAPITOL,
        D.CUATM


        ORDER BY 
        D.CUATM,
        D.CUIIO
```

**This query displays the 6 rows.
It is necessary to output 2 rows, and that would be all the columns.**

This query displays

[image: This query displays.]

**I need to output.**

[image: I need to output.]

Comment: If you have answered your own question then you can either mark the answer as accepted (click the tick below the voting buttons) or, if you do not think the question will benefit other users, you can delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

**May be. But he did not fast. Slower.**

```
SELECT
  A.RIND AS RIND_S,
  B.RIND AS RIND_D,
  A.CUIIO,
  A.CUATM,
  A.CAPITOL,
  A.ID_MD AS ID_MD_S,
  B.ID_MD AS ID_MD_D,
  SUM(A.COL1) AS COL1_S,
  SUM(B.COL1) AS COL1_D
FROM
(
SELECT
      D.CUIIO,
      D.CUATM,
      D.RIND,
      D.ID_MD,
      D.CAPITOL,
      CIS2.NVAL(D.COL1) AS COL1
    FROM
     CIS2.VW_DATA_ALL D



    WHERE
     (D.PERIOADA =:pPERIOADA) AND    
      D.FORM IN (20) AND
      D.CAPITOL IN (1010) AND
      D.RIND IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
      AND D.CUIIO IN (5698200,38985903)

) A
INNER JOIN
(      
 SELECT
      D.CUIIO,
      D.CUATM,
      D.RIND,
      D.ID_MD,
      D.CAPITOL,
      CIS2.NVAL(D.COL1) AS COL1
    FROM
      CIS2.VW_DATA_ALL D


    WHERE
     (D.PERIOADA =:pPERIOADA) AND    
      D.FORM IN (20) AND
      D.CAPITOL IN (1010) AND
      D.RIND NOT IN ('00','--','1','2','3','4','5','6')
     AND D.CUIIO IN (5698200,38985903)

) B ON (A.CUIIO=B.CUIIO)

GROUP BY
  A.RIND,
  B.RIND,
  A.ID_MD,
  B.ID_MD,
  A.CUIIO,
  A.CUATM,
  A.CAPITOL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to do the operations on top of the inline view if you don't know the inside operations of the inline view. Hope below snippet helps. I have tried to get the output as shown below.

```
SELECT MAX(A.RIND_S),
  MAX(A.RIND_D),
  A.CUIIO,
  A.CAPITOL,
  A.CUATM,
  MAX(A.ID_MD_S),
  MAX(A.ID_MD_D),
  MAX(A.COL1_S),
  MAX(A.COL1_D)
FROM
  (SELECT D.RIND_S,
    D.RIND_D,
    D.CUIIO,
    D.CAPITOL,
    D.CUATM,
    D.ID_MD_S,
    D.ID_MD_D,
    SUM(COL1_S) COL1_S,
    SUM(COL1_D) COL1_D
  FROM
    (SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN D.RIND IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
        THEN D.RIND
      END RIND_S,
      CASE
        WHEN D.RIND NOT IN ('00','--','1','2','3','4','5','6')
        THEN D.RIND
      END RIND_D,
      D.CUIIO   AS CUIIO,
      D.CAPITOL AS CAPITOL,
      D.CUATM   AS CUATM ,
      CASE
        WHEN D.ID_MD IN (11788,11789,11790,11791,11792,11793)
        THEN ID_MD
      END AS ID_MD_S,
      CASE
        WHEN D.ID_MD IN (11795,11796,11797,11798,11799,11800,11801,11802,11803,11804,11805,12521,12238,12240,12241,12524,12242)
        THEN ID_MD
      END AS ID_MD_D,
      CASE
        WHEN D.RIND IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
        THEN CIS2.NVAL(D.COL1)
      END AS COL1_S,
      CASE
        WHEN D.RIND NOT IN ('00','--','1','2','3','4','5','6')
        THEN CIS2.NVAL(D.COL1)
      END AS COL1_D
    FROM CIS2.VW_DATA_ALL D
    WHERE (D.PERIOADA =:pPERIOADA)
    AND D.FORM       IN (20)
    AND D.CAPITOL    IN (1010)
    AND D.CUIIO      IN (5698200,38985903)
    ) D
  GROUP BY D.RIND_S,
    D.RIND_D,
    D.ID_MD_S,
    D.ID_MD_D,
    D.CUIIO,
    D.CAPITOL,
    D.CUATM
  )A
GROUP BY A.CUIIO,
  A.CAPITOL,
  A.CUATM;
```